# Processor dependent on two previous processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I have three `PutSQL`-processors. In theorie I could execute them in a simple order: `1 - 2 - 3` since only the third processor needs to be executed after the first two, but `1` and `2` can also run concurrent as they are independent of each other.

To make things faster, I'd like to run 1 & 2 concurrently and trigger the third only after **both** have been successful:

```
1 ---\
      ----> 3 
2 ---/
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs (or maybe I just was looking with the wrong keywords), but is there a processor which operates like an `AND` operator?

Ideally the processor waits for success messages from `1` **and** `2` before sending a success message to `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this ca you would use a **MergeContent** with a common **corrleation_id**
Would be something like:

```
    1 ---\
 A-/        Merge on A ----> 3 
   \ 2 ---/
```

Set the merge as follows:
[image]

You should get a single flowfile to trigger your last step

Comment: What value must the String "my_correlation_id" have? And where do I specifiy it besides the `MergeContent` processor?  I'm guessing "A" is another (e.g. PutSQL) processor in front of the two and the `MergeContent` processor is after the `1` and `2`?

Comment: I literally typed in `my_correlation_id` and the setup still seems to work... Im a bit confused what the ID is for.

Comment: From the docs: "If specified, like FlowFiles will be binned together, where 'like FlowFiles' means FlowFiles that have the same value for this Attribute. If not specified, FlowFiles are bundled by the order in which they are pulled from the queue."  -> since I don't actually transfer data, but only `success` messages, I guess I can leave it empty.

Comment: Yes, it will merge the content based on the correlation id , but since you are not interested inthe content it merge once the num of entries are satified